# Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova

I'm trying to update my cordova project to cordova-ios 6.1.0. Also cordova-plugin-firebasex (10.1.2) exists in the project. When I write `cordova platform add ios@6.1.0`, I get this error (picture).

How can I fix it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pods. Read the doc [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#ios-specific) . To install pods, read [this](https://cocoapods.org/)

Comment: It doesn't work, the same error after `pod install`.

Comment: This fixed it for me:
    `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
    `cd platforms/ios`
    `arch -x86_64 pod install`